# How to call SQL Function directly from CodeSmith generated service dlls

Tags: asp.net, sql, codesmith, .nettiers

In a project we are using CodeSmith to generate database layer, Codesmith seperate creates service classes for each SQL View and SQL Table, using these service classes we can call StoredProcedures that has prefix "*ViewOrTableName*".

My problem is that I am unable to directly call any storedprocedure/view or function.

If any body atleast know how to call a function and get response please let me know

Thanks,
Imran Rizvi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using the .netTiers templates. You would need to access the view or stored procedure data (result set) via the component layer (http://www.nettiers.com/ComponentLayer.ashx). You should have methods that are generated for views and stored procedures once you select a view to generate / enable support for custom stored procedures while configuring the generation options (http://www.nettiers.com/Database.ashx).

Comment: No , I don't want to name SP with prefix of _View/Table_ name and directly want to call it , it seems that is not possible.

Comment: You don't have to, there is a property you can set for the name matching format..